# changing maxLength property for password input not working

Tags: javascript, html, input, dojo, passwords

I have a password input control and by default, the component that creates the password control sets a maxLength of 32. I am trying to change the maxLength of the password input to 128 characters using the dojo.addOnLoad() event handler. The event handler fires but setting the maxLength attribute to 128 doesn't seem to actually work. The limit still seems to be set to the old value : 32.

What workarounds are available ?

P.S : I'm using chrome 20 on windows and firefox 13.

Thank you

Comment: Did you use `setAttribute` to set the new `maxLength`?

Comment: Are you using declarative or programmatic approach?

Comment: I'm using a framework that's built on top of dojo. So I called var passwordControl = dijit.byId("idofpasswordinput"); passwordControl.maxLength = 128; That didn't work.

Comment: No, I didn't use setAttribute ? Is that how it's done ?

Comment: @MaxArt : after trying setAttribute, it worked. If you post this comment as an answer, I will approve it.

Comment: @anjanb Ok, it could be good for future reference. Posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `setAttribute` instead:

```
pwdField.setAttribute("maxlength", 128);
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s difficult to say what is going on, but at least in a simple case, setting maxLength (with that exact spelling) to override a maxlength attribute seems to work well, as expected, both in practical testing and when inspecting the DOM. Make sure you are accessing the right object, and do the assignment the simplest possible way, like `document.getElementById('yourPasswordFieldID').maxLength = 128`.

Comment: I'm using a framework that's built on top of dojo. So I called var passwordControl = dijit.byId("idofpasswordinput"); passwordControl.maxLength = 128; That didn't work.